# player.markers is not a function error while using videojs markers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js, markers

I want to add markers to my videojs player timelime. I have see how to implemented it and already implemented it few months back and it worked that time. Now in my other project I want to use the same. But it is giving me errors in console like this (below) and I am not able to see my markers on player timeline.

[image]
[image]

```
class Player extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            player: {}
        };
    }
componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    var player = videojs(this.refs.video, this.props.options).ready(function () {
        self.player = this;
        self.player.on('play', self.handlePlay);
    });

    // $.get('URL-TO-FETCH-DATA-FROM', function(result) {
    //     if (this.isMounted()) {
    //         this.setState({
    //             dataVar1: result
    //         });
    //     }
    // }.bind(this));

    if (this.props.onPlayerInit) this.props.onPlayerInit(player);





    player.markers({
        markerStyle: {},
        markers: this.props.marker_store,
        onMarkerReached: function () {
            // player.pause();
        },
    });
    this.setState({player: player});

}



handlePlay() {
    console.log("handle play ")

}

render() {
    var props = blacklist(this.props, 'children', 'className', 'src', 'type', 'onPlay');
    props.className = cx(this.props.className, 'videojs', 'video-js vjs-default-skin', 'vjs-big-play-centered');


    assign(props, {
        ref: 'video',
        controls: true,
    });

    return (
            <video {... props}>
                <source src={videoSrc} type="video/mp4"/>
            </video>
       )
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        marker_store:state.markerReducer
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Player);
```

and these are the lines of markers.js plugin code which is throwing videojs not defined error

```
    };
    }

    videojs.plugin('markers', registerVideoJsMarkersPlugin);


})(jQuery, window.videojs);
```

How should I solve it so that I am able to see the markers on my player?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to put ref in video tag.

```
<video ref="video" {... props}>
   <source src={videoSrc} type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Comment: That is already there in assign(props, {
        ref: 'video',
        controls: true,
    });

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that. I am curious to know how does that add ref key to props. Does that work like object.assign.

Answer (score 0):

In angular case, we have to import the .js code to the component typescript file, like this:

```
import 'videojs-markers';
```

Check if it is necessary also in your case.